# state is undefined in react native

Tags: react-native

I am read **SOAP APIs** in react native using **XMLHttpRequest**. Everything is fine. But I unable to read state inside **'onreadystatechange'**. When I try to read state, it's through me **'undefined state error'**. In my code, I want to show loader when a request is running and hide it when the request is completed. I think a state is destroying inside 'onreadystatechange'.

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
//import libraries
import React, { Component } from "react";
import renderIf from "../../main/renderIf";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  ToastAndroid
} from "react-native";

import Constant from "../../../utils/Constant";
import Loader from "../../main/loader";
var XMLParser = require("react-xml-parser");

// create a component
class Screen extends Component {

  url =
    "some url";

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      loading: false,
      error: ""
    };
  }


  SOAPRequest(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", this.url, true);

    // build SOAP request
    var sr =
      "<soapenv:Envelope>" +
      "<soapenv:Header/>" +
      "<soapenv:Body>" +
      "<ns:InquiryRequest>" +
      "</ns:InquiryRequest>" +
      "</soapenv:Body>" +
      "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          console.log("success", xmlhttp.responseText);

          console.log("--------------------------------------");
          console.log(this.state);    // here I get Undefined state Object

        }
      }
    };

    // Send the POST request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    xmlhttp.send(sr);
  };


  onSubmit = () => {

      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state));
      this.state.loading = true;
      this.setState({ ...this.state });
      this.SOAPRequest(this);

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
        enableAutomaticScroll={true}
        enableOnAndroid={true}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Loader loading={this.state.loading} />       
          </View>
          <View>
          <RkButton
                onPress={this.onSubmit}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                >
                  Submit
                </Text>
              </RkButton>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to bind the function `SOAPRequest` The easiest way to do it is to make it an arrow function

```
SOAPRequest = () => {
```

Then you can stop `this` from getting lost by assigning it to a variable inside your function.

```
SOAPRequest = () => {
    const that = this; // assign this to the variable that
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", this.url, true);

    // build SOAP request
    var sr =
      "<soapenv:Envelope>" +
      "<soapenv:Header/>" +
      "<soapenv:Body>" +
      "<ns:InquiryRequest>" +
      "</ns:InquiryRequest>" +
      "</soapenv:Body>" +
      "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          console.log("success", xmlhttp.responseText);

          console.log("--------------------------------------");
          console.log(that.state);    // use that instead of this

        }
      }
    };

    // Send the POST request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    xmlhttp.send(sr);
};
```